# AJAX - URL to Data Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I'm using ajax and I'd like to somehow turn the current page's url into a data object used for ajax method. I'm using `window.location.search` to get the current url of the page and I'm not sure the best way to turn the url into a data object used for ajax.

**URL (window.location.search):**

```
?pickup-location=Orlando+Intl+Airport+%28MCO%29%2C+FL&dropoff-location=&pickup-date=07%2F16%2F2018&pickup-time=12%3A00&dropoff-date=07%2F17%2F2018&dropoff-time=12%3A00&discount-code-company=&pagination=1
```

**End Goal:**

```
data: {
    pickup-location: "Orlando+Intl+Airport",
    .... etc ...
    pagination: page
},
```

Comment: Are you asking for a library or if a JavaScript function can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm pretty sure @zero298 is correct there are multiple answers on that post that cover what you need.

Comment: doesn't it already work with the query string? Unless you want to transmit it as JSON, the data are transformed into that (URL) format anyways.